# Why is there no online record of pentagram area formula?

Tags: geometry, area

I'm talking about the short version of the area of a pentagram inscribed in a circle when the radius is given and so **Area** $=1.123r^2$.

I only got this formula from a book but I researched about it and nothing came up.

I tried to apply the short formula in other problems online and I still got the correct answer.

Comment: What do you mean by pentagram? A regular star with five vertices, like $\bigstar$ ?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be about math at all. Does the area of every concievable figure need to be recorded online?

Comment: I expect 1.123 is not the exact value of that constant. Any source that gives the formula is much more likely to give the exact value (in terms of $\pi$ or $\sqrt 2$ or whatever). Anyway, "why can't I find this information" isn't a math question, but if you want to ask where you *can* find it, or what the formula *is*, or how it is derived, that would be on topic.

Comment: I believe the exact value is $\frac{5\sin(18^{\circ})\sin(36^{\circ})}{\sin(54^{\circ})}$

Comment: Yes a regular 5 star pentagram. I'm asking the validity of this constant term 1.123 and it's variable r^2 to why it still applies to problems yet there is no other credible source other than my local book. It's confusing since this is a common topic in geometry and the solution is quite tedious compared to the simple formula

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Are you asking about "the validity of this constant term 1.123", i.e. why that constant is (approximately) correct? Or are you asking why that is given only in your "local book"? Those are two very different questions, and only the first is appropriate for this site. If you mean the first, you should change the title of this question before it is closed.

Answer (score 3):

A regular star with five vertices ($\bigstar$) and unit circumradius can be seen as the disjoint union of ten triangles having a side with unit length and the angles adjacent to it equal to $\frac{\pi}{5}$ and $\frac{\pi}{10}$. By the sine theorem, the area of a triangle made that way is: $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{10}\sin\frac{\pi}{5}}{\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\cot\frac{\pi}{5}+\cot\frac{\pi}{10}}$$
hence the area of the "pentagram" inscribed in a circle with radius $R$ is given by:
$$ \frac{5R^2}{\cot\frac{\pi}{5}+\cot\frac{\pi}{10}}=\frac{5R^2}{2}\sqrt{\frac{25-11\sqrt{5}}{2}} \approx \color{red}{1.12257}\,R^2.$$